# React Native button press to control imported class state

Tags: javascript, react-native

I don't know the exact title for my case, so I'll explain in detail.

**Below is my popup class.**

```
export default class Popup extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isshowing: true,
        }
    }

    handleShow(){
        this.setState({isshowing:true})
    }


    return(
            <View style={{}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={{}}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({isshowing:false})}
                        >
                            <Text>X</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

*I've omitted unnecessary things such as style, etc.*

I want to control the popup classes visibility via the state.

I can make the close button since the closing button is inside popup class but I want to make the external button (inside the main class) make this popup visible since I'm importing popup class.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass props from the class you are calling `<Popup>` from like :

```
export default class Parent extends Component{

....
<Button
 title={"Make Popup visible Button"}
 onPress={()=>this.setState({isPopupVisible:true})
/>

<Popup isVisible={this.state.isPopupVisible} />

....
}
```

and in Popup class, you should assign the **passed isVisible props** from the parent class to the Popup class state - **isshowing**.

If the popup is not using any state(as in many cases), you should consider using SFC(Stateless Functional Component). It is much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks!
I made Popup's props change in life-cycle functions.